# Apple / Android pay in nativeScript

Tags: plugins, nativescript, applepay

what is the best way to use Apple / Android pay in nativeScript for in App purchase? Is there any plugin around? Can anyone give me a direction?

Comment: @Time Schnoelzer Is there an update on this? Did you find a solution or did you use the answer of Vladimir Enchev? I am facing a similar problem that might not be solved by that answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such plugin at the moment however you can create easily new one by using some already available cocoa pod for example for iOS:
https://cocoapods.org/?q=Apple%20Pay

You can use this repo to get started with Google Pay:
https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart

Here is also more info how to create {N} plugins:
http://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugins

Comment: this answer is outdated. There is a nativescript purchace plugin, check the other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-purchase

Currently, it is only supporting IOS, but guessing will have Android support soon.

Answer (score 2):

nativescript-purchase currently supports both android and iOS.
And it is constantly being updated.